# resume file transfer if aborted

Tags: bash, unix, rsync, scp

I am transferring very large files using rsync or scp . 
There are times when the transfer is aborted so i need to monitor it and resume it manually.
Can you help me to write a script that will resume a file transfer that was aborted or was completed but the files (source and destination) are not in the same size (in this case the transfer will restart from beginning- first it will remove the destination file and the transfer will be restarted).
one thing to mention is that when i connect to the source server i need to provide a password, so i would like the password to be a parameter of the script

Answer (score 2):

You need `-P` and `--partial` options.

From the man page:

```
--partial By default, rsync will delete any partially transferred file if the transfer
         is interrupted. In some circumstances it is more desirable to keep partially
         transferred files. Using the --partial option tells rsync to keep the partial
         file which should make a subsequent transfer of the rest of the file much faster.

  -P     The -P option is equivalent to --partial --progress.   Its  pur-
         pose  is to make it much easier to specify these two options for
         a long transfer that may be interrupted.
```

So if you want to sync (continu syncing) directories:

```
sudo rsync -azvvP /home/path/folder1/ /home/path/folder2
```

You can find some additional infos here:

- [Can rsync resume after being interrupted?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48298/can-rsync-resume-after-being-interrupted)

To resume it automatically, just run it in a loop:

```
RETRY_IN=5
while rsync -azvvP /home/path/folder1/ /home/path/folder2
do
   echo "Retrying in ${RETRY_IN} sec"
   sleep "${RETRY_IN}"
done
```

Comment: OK. how can i make RSYNC or SCP resume transfer automatically (in transfer was aborted not by user) ?

Comment: @MichaelNathanSellers: Just start in a loop. See my update